# Userform Checkbox: End if without block if error

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

Trying to get cell P3 to show "True" or "Yes" if VBA userform checkbox is checked.

Any tips would be helpful. Code below results in Compile Error: End If with no block if error.

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True _
Then Range("P3").Value = "True"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you want to have `then` on an extra line you have to write it like that

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True _
Then
    Range("P3").Value = "True"
End If
```

Secondly `CheckBox1.Value = True` is also not necessary as  `CheckBox1.Value`is of type `boolean`.

My preferred piece of code would probably look like that

```
If CheckBox1.Value Then
    Range("P3").Value = "True"
End If
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks. I'll remember this for the future. I'm feeling slightly embarrassed that I didn't know this. It's been a while since I've worked VBA.